# How do I get a multiple-line subtitle in google sheet charts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am creating a bar chart in google sheet, recording it with a macro, and running the code for different data cases.
When the subtitle is too long, there is missing text on the chart, shown with ellipses (...)
Increasing the chart's width reveals more of the text but not all.
Increasing the chart's height does nothing! (It reveals a long title, but not a long subtitle!)

Adding a line break doesn't work. When using one, all I can see is the first line of the subtitle, while the others stay completely hidden...

How can I have a subtitle that shows all of the text I want to display?
Given that titles are responsive in both the horizontal and vertical axes, it's really odd for subtitles not to be.

Thank you

---- Edit ----

The script helps automate things, but I don't think that it adds new functionalities. That being said, the code I use is the following:

```
function Macro3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asBarChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getActiveRange())
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(4)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('su', SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheebtitlet().getRange("B2:B2").getValue())
  .setOption('title', SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1:B1").getValue())
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#1a1a1a')
  .setOption('subtitleTextStyle.color', '#999999')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B4:B4").getValue())
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setYAxisTitle(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A4:A4").getValue())
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setPosition(2, 1, 30, 0)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

I wanted to include a screenshot of the Google sheet this macro is used upon, but this is my 1st post on stackoverflow and apparently I need at least 10 reputation to post images.
If you think it would help to share this screenshot and there is a neat way of doing it, please let me know.
Thanks again

Comment: Could you share a copy of your script and a sanitized version of your data? Without this it is difficult to visualize what is happening and help you to find a solution.

Comment: @Emel the problem is not the script, it is that Chart subtitles are not responsive. no amount of scripting will change that fact.

Comment: From what I see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options), you can change the `subtitleTextStyle` (including the `fontSize`) from the script, so you can set the script in a way that the the font size is inversely proportional to the length of the string, making it responsive. So if you share your script, it will be easier to help you with this.

Comment: As the macro saves in a script from the actions from the UI, you can manipulate it to add some extra functionality as discussed previously. I don't see any updates on your question, please add the code from the macro.

Comment: @Emel, thanks for the reply. I just updated the post. Changing the font size is helpful, but on a really long subtitle is of no real use. The text becomes too small to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current state it is not possible to add multiple lines to the subtitles of Google Sheets charts. Therefore I recommend you to go to `Help` > `Help Sheets to Improve` and add this request. Alternatively, you can use this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) to request this functionality for Apps Script, for example, allowing [`EmbeddedCharts`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart) to have titles written with [`HTMLService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service).

Possible workarounds:

1. **Change the font size according to the string length.**

As I told you in the comments, you can measure the amount of words your subtitle has and according to that, apply different font sizes. For example:

```js
function calcFontSize(subtitle){
  const lenS = subtitle.split(" ").length
  if(lenS > 12) return 8
  if(len <= 12) return 12
 }
// Inside your macro
.setOption(
    'subtitleTextStyle.fontSize',
     calcFontSize(sheet.getRange('B2:B2').getValue())
)
```

- **PROS** : You have a "responsive" subtitle.
- **CONS**: As you say `In long texts ... The text becomes too small to read`

2. **Use [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts) to create your chart**

As this service allows you to add jump lines to your title, you can achieve what you want:

```js
function createGoogleChart() {
  // extracted from here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts
  const data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Month')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Online')
    .addRow(['January', 10, 1])
    .addRow(['February', 12, 1])
    .addRow(['March', 20, 2])
    .addRow(['April', 25, 3])
    .addRow(['May', 30, 4])
    .build();
  const chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
    .setDataTable(data)
    .setStacked()
    .setRange(0, 40)
    .setTitle("My title\nMy long long long long long \n long long long long \n subtitle")
    .build();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertImage(
    chart.getAs('image/png'), 10, 10
  )
}
```

- **PROS** : You can achieve what you need.
- **CONS**:

  - You insert a still image (not editable)
  - There is no default subtitle option
  - You have to build it from Apps Script, and adapt it to your macro

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I have put in a request as you suggested. 
I also wanted to upvote your answer but I get the message "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it! Consider accepting the answer for visibility